# Integration involving two DiracDelta with variable limit

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, symbolic, distributions, convolution, generalized-function

I want to write a code to evaluate

$$ \int_0^{t-1}\frac{\delta(z-1)}{z}\frac{\delta(t-z-1)}{t-z}dz$$

which should gives the answer $$\frac{\delta(t-2)}{t-1}.$$

I tried to write the code

```
Integrate[DiracDelta[z - 1]/z * DiracDelta[t - z - 1]/(t - z), {z, 0, t - 1}]
```

but it didn't give the answer.

How should I write the code to give the expected answer?

Comment: Why should `(DiracDelta[-2 + t] HeavisideTheta[-2 + t])/(-1 + t)` be true? Can you kindly give a reference?

Comment: Are you asking why mathematically should we get that answer?

Comment: I asked for a reference for it.  What is  the reason you think that the right answer should be $\frac{\delta(t-2)}{t-1}$? Hope I am clear.

Comment: Just calculate it by hand ✋

Comment: This assumes t>2?

Answer (score 3):

Workaround:

```
FourierTransform[Integrate[InverseFourierTransform[
DiracDelta[z - 1]/z*DiracDelta[t - q z - 1]/(t - z), q, w], {z, 0,
t - 1}, Assumptions -> t \[Element] Reals], w, q] /. q -> 1

(*(DiracDelta[-2 + t] HeavisideTheta[-2 + t])/(-1 + t)*)
```

Solution with **Maple 2023.1** :

[image]

Comment: [Fourier transforms of generalized functions](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Fourier_transform_of_a_generalized_function) are hard matter. It's unclear to me how to justify `FourierTransform[Integrate[InverseFourierTransform...`. Also `InverseFourierTransform[
 DiracDelta[z - 1]/z*DiracDelta[t - q z - 1]/(t - z), q, w]`  is running without any response for a long time. All that is built on the sand.  Last, but not least:  why is `(DiracDelta[-2 + t] HeavisideTheta[-2 + t])/(-1 + t)` true?

Comment: @user64494 .My sand is **GOLD**.

Comment: MariuszIwaniuk (@ does not work.): I prefer arguments over emotional words.

Comment: `InverseFourierTransform[
 DiracDelta[z - 1]/z*DiracDelta[t - q z - 1]/(t - z), q, w]`  results in `(E^(-I (-1 + t) w) DiracDelta[-1 + z])/(Sqrt[2 \[Pi]] (-1 + t))`. Can somebody give a reference to this result? It would be kind of that person.

Comment: BTW, Maple 2023.1 produces $$ \frac{\mathrm{Dirac}\! \left(z-1\right) {\mathrm e}^{\frac{\mathrm{I} \left(-t+1\right) w}{z}} \sqrt{2}}{2 z \left(t-z\right) {| z|} \sqrt{\pi}}$$ for it.

Comment: Here is the Maple's code `MmaTranslator:-FromMma("InverseFourierTransform[\n DiracDelta[z - 1]/z*DiracDelta[t - q z - 1]/(t - z), q, w]");
%;
`

Comment: @user64494 With Maple: `eval((inttrans:-invfourier(int(inttrans:-fourier(Dirac(z - 1)*Dirac(-q*z + t - 1)/(z*(t - z)), q, w), z = 0 .. t - 1), w, q) assuming (0 < q, t in real)), q = 1)` give me the same answer: `Heaviside(t - 2)*Dirac(t - 2)/(t - 1)`.

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk: Thank you. However, that does not explain the difference in the results. Also can you give a reference to the result of `InverseFourierTransform[  DiracDelta[z - 1]/z*DiracDelta[t - q z - 1]/(t - z), q, w]`? It would be nice of you.

Comment: @user64494 try: `FourierTransform[
 InverseFourierTransform[DiracDelta[t - q z - 1], q, w], w, q]` and $$\frac{\delta \left(q-\frac{t}{z}+\frac{1}{z}\right)}{| z| }=\delta (-q z+t-1)$$ See properties: https://math.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Differential_Equations/Introduction_to_Partial_Differential_Equations_(Herman)/09%3A_Transform_Techniques_in_Physics/9.04%3A_The_Dirac_Delta_Function

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk: Thank you. I got it. It's still unclear to me how to justify `FourierTransform[Integrate[InverseFourierTransform.... `.

Comment: The product `DiracDelta[-2 + t] HeavisideTheta[-2 + t]` is not defined because both distributions have $ \{2\}$ as their support.See  "Problem of multiplying distributions" in [the Wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics)) as a first reading.

Comment: Also [the documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DiracDelta.html?q=DiracDelta) says "Products of distributions with coinciding singular support cannot be defined" and presents as an example `Integrate[HeavisideTheta[x] DiracDelta[x], {x, -1, 1}]`.

Comment: As for the claimed result, yes, it's probably incorrect. Treating the `DiracDelta` functional as a function is sometimes appropriate, and sometimes plain wrong.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau. Ok, then what is the correct answer ?

Comment: It's undefined. The integral cannot have a member of the singular set as an endpoint of the integration.

Answer (score 3):

Approximate the DiracDelta by the normal distribution

```
   Integrate[DiracDelta[z-1 ]/z 1/Sqrt[2 \[Pi] s] E^(-(t-z-1)^2/(2s^2)),  
     {z,0,t-1}]
```

$$\fbox{$\frac{\theta (t-2) e^{-\frac{(t-2)^2}{2 s^2}}}{\sqrt{2 \pi } \sqrt{s}}\text{ if }t\in \mathbb{R}$}$$

Now let $s\to 0$, evaluating $\theta$ at its jump. Good example to show that products of singular distributions are undefined.

Comment: All that is built on the sand.  If you look in W. Rudin, Functional analysis, Chap. 6,7, you will see that $\frac{e^{-\frac{(t-2)^2}{2 s^2}}}{\sqrt{2 \pi } \sqrt{s}}$ converges to the $\delta$-distribution in the weak topology. The pointwise convergence makes no sense.

Comment: The product `DiracDelta[-2 + t] HeavisideTheta[-2 + t]` is not defined because both distributions have $ \{2\}$ as their support.See  "Problem of multiplying distributions" in [the Wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics)) as a first reading.

Comment: Also [the documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DiracDelta.html?q=DiracDelta) says "Products of distributions with coinciding singular support cannot be defined" and presents as an example `Integrate[HeavisideTheta[x] DiracDelta[x], {x, -1, 1}]`.

Answer (score 2):

`Mathematica` needs the info `t \[Element] Reals` !

Using `DiracDelta` as a limit (see @RolandF's approach) we get

```
dirac = Function[x, Exp[-(x^2/(2 eps))]/Sqrt[2 Pi eps]]

Integrate[DiracDelta [z - 1]/z* dirac[t - z - 1]/(t - z), {z, 0, t - 1},Assumptions ->{ Element[t, Reals] }]
(*(E^(-((-2 + t)^2/(2 eps))) HeavisideTheta[-2 + t])/(Sqrt[eps]Sqrt[2 \[Pi]] (-1 + t))*)
```

Using the definition of `dirac`  the result follows to

`DiracDelta[t-2]  HeavisideTheta[-2 + t] /  (-1 + t)`

which confirms the expectation of QP and the result @MariuszIwaniuk !

Comment: The product `DiracDelta[t-2]  HeavisideTheta[-2 + t]` is not defined because both distributions have $\{2\}$ as their support (see "Problem of multiplying distributions" in [the Wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics))).

Comment: Knowing that the definitions of both distributions are well defined I see no reason why the product shouldn't be defined too!

Comment: Did you look in the linked Wiki article before having replied?

Comment: Also [the documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DiracDelta.html?q=DiracDelta) says "Products of distributions with coinciding singular support cannot be defined" and presents as an example `Integrate[HeavisideTheta[x] DiracDelta[x], {x, -1, 1}]`.